# Is it possible to install Bada SDK into eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, bada

I'd like to know if it is possible, because I'd prefer to have only one eclipse running on my computer.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The [Bada SDK development tool](http://developer.bada.com/apis/docs/commonpage.do?menu=MC01040000) seems to be a full RCP (Rich Client Platform) application, not a simple Eclipse plugin. Its [installation procedure](http://static.bada.com/contents/docs/resources_1.2.0/com.osp.devguide.help/html/FramesetMain.html) supports only a stand-alone mode.
You can check out its sources (423Mo) at [opensource.samsung.com](http://opensource.samsung.com/) (type bada in the search field) and see how the project is actually structured.

Comment: I have Eclipse and BadaIDE installed, and as everybody knows, badaIDE is based on eclipse, that's why I'd like to know if it should be possible, like we can do with the android SDK.

Comment: @Specter: I suppose you have both installed as separate product. For a RCP deployed as a standalone project (http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseRCP/article.html#deployproduct), I would try copying all features and plugins jar from that standalone into your eclipse, and see if it picks up said RCP.

Comment: If Eclipse is part of Bada SDK, then why not re-use it as your main Eclipse, instead of the other one you can install by choice.